Copilot is not working is WSL remote connection?
I installed the copilot extension, it is working fine in window but when I use in WSL remote connection, it gives error and doesn't work Do I need to follow different step to make it work in WSL?
I uninstall the extension and connect it again, but that's not working

Maybe uninstall it, and follow what worked for me:

Install wsl
Install vscode
Open with code . in wsl terminal
Install Copilot and login 
Make sure to the installation is in wsl, that green-ish icon at the bottom-left means it was installed in wsl properly.
Then, I only had this setting {"github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true} in settings.json

